# Changes to volatile variable only occur when stepping through code or optimisation turned off

Tags: c, optimization, microcontroller, volatile

I am programing a TI TM4C microcontroller and stuck with some unusual behavior where the controller is not working as I expect it.

I expect the volatile keyword to work such that any reads or writes carried out in either interrupts or the main loop, are read and written into ram preventing optimisation in local registers.

In my code is set up roughly as follows.

```
volatile bool blinker=false;

void main()
    {
    setupTimers();

    while (1){
        if (blinker){
            set_lcd_to_thing_1();
        } else {
            set_lcd_to_thing_2();
        }
    }
}

void timer_interrupt(){ // Is run every 250ms
    blinker = !blinker;
    clear_interrupt_flag();
}
```

This is what I would have thought of as a textbook example of where volatile should be used, as it needs to be ensured that the if statement does not get optimised away.

However this code, works with optimisation turned off (which as I understand it means everything is treated as volatile), when optimisation is turned on however the blinking does not occur, curiously if I place a breakpoint in the interrupt I can see that the value is getting toggled, If I place the interrupt in the main loop it does not get toggled and is always false.

Even more confusingly If I change my interrupt to the below, everything works as expected, even with optimisation.

```
void timer_interrupt(){ // Is run every 250ms
    blinker = !blinker;
    some_function_call();
    clear_interrupt_flag();
}
```

Digging further into this issue I have noticed that when debugging, if I step through the code line by line, the issue still occurs, however when I step through the code, line by line of assembly the led toggles correctly.

---

**EDIT**

As requested here is a cut down version. It requires tivaware, and should run on the EK-TM4C1294XL development board. I am using CCS version 7 to compile and flash the board.

```
/*################################################

Minimum example, where volatile does not take effect

#################################################*/

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "inc/hw_gpio.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/tm4c1294ncpdt.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"
#include "driverlib/rom.h"
#include "driverlib/rom_map.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/timer.h"
#include "driverlib/interrupt.h"
#include "drivers/pinout.h"

#define SYSCLOCK 120000000L

// PORT L IO
#define LED_2 GPIO_PIN_1

// ****** Variables ******
volatile bool digit_blink = false;
volatile int fo = 0;

void dummyfunc(void){
    fo += 1;
}

void InitTimers(void){
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_TIMER2);

    // *** Timer2 Used to blink the display
    TimerConfigure(TIMER2_BASE,TIMER_CFG_PERIODIC);
    TimerLoadSet(TIMER2_BASE,TIMER_A,SYSCLOCK/4);//Period of 0.25 Seconds
}

void InitIO(void){
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOL); // Front Panel LEDs

    // LED Setup
    GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, LED_2);
    GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, LED_2,GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD); //Set Output
    GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, LED_2 ,0);
}

int main(void)
{
    //
    // Run from the PLL at 120 MHz.
    //
    MAP_SysCtlClockFreqSet((SYSCTL_XTAL_25MHZ |
                           SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN |
                           SYSCTL_USE_PLL |
                           SYSCTL_CFG_VCO_480), SYSCLOCK);

    PinoutSet(false,false); // Library function that sets up UART and USB IO.

    InitTimers();
    InitIO();

    // Interrupts
    IntEnable(INT_TIMER2A);
    TimerIntEnable(TIMER2_BASE,TIMER_TIMA_TIMEOUT);

    IntMasterEnable();
    TimerEnable(TIMER2_BASE,TIMER_A);

    while (1){
        if (digit_blink)
            GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, LED_2,LED_2); // Write to LCD would be here
        else
            GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, LED_2,0x0); // Write to LCD would be here
    }
}

// Interrupts
void Timer2IntHandler(void){ // Blinks a display segment
    digit_blink = !digit_blink;
    dummyfunc(); // If this line is commented the led will not blink.
    TimerIntClear(TIMER2_BASE, TIMER_TIMA_TIMEOUT);
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

Disassembly without function commented optimised level 1 (works)
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/40c58709cdac7dc76f0840e0cc9a5dbd

Disassembly with function commented optimised level 1 (doesn't work)
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9c874e5810cd0241360f87161428cf0d

Disassembly with function commented not optimised (works)
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e0bf41ed4beb923c09651b09551809db

Comment: Can you examine the assembly or compiled code?

Comment: I think we're going to need a [mcve]. (You can't hand us all microcontrollers, but you should at least be able to hand us something that compiles, runs, and produces the effect you're asking about when you run it on your microcontroller.)

Comment: Could it be that because you have no delays in the `while(1)` loop, you don't see the effect on the lcd because `blinker` toggles to fast?

Comment: What does your platform's documentation say about `volatile` and interrupt code? If it doesn't say it should work, then it's not required to.

Comment: please show the disassembly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz see http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spnu151m/spnu151m.pdf page 94.

Comment: @Pablo I am not sure how as the main loop is not toggling the value, the 250ms interrupt timer is.

Comment: Could it be that the lcd is not fast enough to change every 250ms?

Comment: It's been many years since I wrote arm assembler, I'm very rusty. I checked both main functions (the "works" link and "does not work" link) and where `digit_blink` gets evaluated, the code is the same, the code of the interrupt handler is however different.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, In my minimum code example I am toggling an LED and the same behavior occurs.

Comment: I'd rather see a disassembly of optimized vs not optimized.

Comment: @user58697 I have added an additional gist to the question.

Comment: 1) idea: For debugging purposes, replace `bool blinker` and instead, increment in the ISR and compare to a level like `if (blinker&7 >= 4)`.  Easier to see what might be happening 2) Are `set_lcd_to_thing_1()` or `set_lcd_to_thing_2()` synchronized to the timer in any way?  3)  If `volatile` defined out like `#define volatile` someplace?

Comment: in Standard C, your program has undefined behaviour because the ISR might write the bool simultaneously with it being read by the main thread. To have the code work properly, in Standard C, you need to declare the `bool` as `_Atomic` also, or disable interrupts while you are reading the `bool` in the main thread.  I don't know what behaviour your particular platform implements or expects in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to isolate the disassembly to just the relevant parts, and post them in this question do not use a link.

Try something like this.

```
void set_lcd_to_thing_1( void );
void set_lcd_to_thing_2( void );
volatile unsigned int blinker=0;
void main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if(blinker)
        {
            set_lcd_to_thing_1();
        } else
        {
            set_lcd_to_thing_2();
        }
    }
}
void timer_interrupt()
{
    blinker = !blinker;
}
```

gcc -O2 optimization.

```
00000000 <timer_interrupt>:
   0:   e59f2010    ldr r2, [pc, #16]   ; 18 <timer_interrupt+0x18>
   4:   e5923000    ldr r3, [r2]
   8:   e2733001    rsbs    r3, r3, #1
   c:   33a03000    movcc   r3, #0
  10:   e5823000    str r3, [r2]
  14:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  18:   00000000    

00000000 <main>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e59f4020    ldr r4, [pc, #32]   ; 2c <main+0x2c>
   8:   e5943000    ldr r3, [r4]
   c:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
  10:   0a000003    beq 24 <main+0x24>
  14:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <set_lcd_to_thing_1>
  18:   e5943000    ldr r3, [r4]
  1c:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
  20:   1afffffb    bne 14 <main+0x14>
  24:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <set_lcd_to_thing_2>
  28:   eafffff6    b   8 <main+0x8>
  2c:   00000000
```

This is the object not the whole binary the zeros at the end of the function get filled in by the linker with the address to blinker.

In this case it is clear that the volatile is working.

For amusement save an instruction (and make it more readable) and remove the need for zeroing .bss.

```
void set_lcd_to_thing_1( void );
void set_lcd_to_thing_2( void );
volatile unsigned int blinker;
void main()
{
    blinker=0;
    while (1)
    {
        if(blinker)
        {
            set_lcd_to_thing_1();
        } else
        {
            set_lcd_to_thing_2();
        }
    }
}
void timer_interrupt()
{
    blinker = ~blinker;
}
```

Optimized gives

```
00000000 <timer_interrupt>:
   0:   e59f200c    ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; 14 <timer_interrupt+0x14>
   4:   e5923000    ldr r3, [r2]
   8:   e1e03003    mvn r3, r3
   c:   e5823000    str r3, [r2]
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  14:   00000000    

00000000 <main>:
   0:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
   4:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   8:   e59f4024    ldr r4, [pc, #36]   ; 34 <main+0x34>
   c:   e5843000    str r3, [r4]
  10:   e5943000    ldr r3, [r4]
  14:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
  18:   0a000003    beq 2c <main+0x2c>
  1c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <set_lcd_to_thing_1>
  20:   e5943000    ldr r3, [r4]
  24:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
  28:   1afffffb    bne 1c <main+0x1c>
  2c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <set_lcd_to_thing_2>
  30:   eafffff6    b   10 <main+0x10>
  34:   00000000
```

If you simplify a version of your project, say one that doesnt necessarily function, but builds and the disassembly is contained.  Do you see the same kind of thing going on (dont expect two different compilers to produce the same code).

Comment: Note when you get around to examining the disassembly you will see that the volatile worked for both cases (first two cases, didnt bother with the third).  Your problem is elsewhere.  I think you need to completely re-write your question as so far it doesnt appear to be related to the volatile variable.

Comment: What does your scope show with respect to the gpio pin driving(/sinking) the led?  The function may just be adding enough time to allow you to visually see the led blink and that is all.  Do you have two leds?  Can you alternate them one on the other off, and vice versa?  Do they both appear to be on when "not working"?

Comment: what happens when you change your interrupt rate to 1 second?  2 seconds?  etc?

Comment: what if you dont run it so fast?  out of curiosity did you set the flash wait states to compensate for that flash speed?

Comment: I edited the question a bit, but I also seem to have solved the problem but I dont understand why. If I swap the line clearing the timer interrupt flag and the line that toggles the value, everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: again it sounds like a race condition, the volatile did its job, that wasnt the problem.

Comment: I think I found a clue here https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/tiva_arm/f/908/t/306546 and will add more detail on the problem and solution tomorrow, would you have any recommendations on what I should do to this question/answer to make sure it is useful to people in the future?

Comment: looks like it is already documented there, links are not useful to stackoverflow, as part of the question or of the answer.  you should confirm this was your issue as well.  and post an answer to your own question, will see if this question survives...should also isolate the assembly language from your links that are relevant to the volatile which they show was not the issue.

Comment: My answer was not intended to survive, but dont think this question is really in a form to survive either. will see...